# C# / Unable to cast object of type to type

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, polymorphism

Iam trying to create an object. but the program throw an error :
Unable to cast object of type
here is a code that generate my issue:

```
public class AnimalBase
{
    public AnimalBase()
    {
        this.ArriveTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public DateTime ArriveTime { get; set; }
    public int ageAnimal { get; set; }

    public int poidsAnimal { get; set; }

    public virtual string typeAnimal
    {
        get
        {
            return "AnimalBase";
        }
    }

    public  static  AnimalBase DoSomething(string value)
    {
        AnimalBase animalbase = new AnimalBase();
        animalbase.ArriveTime = DateTime.Now;
        animalbase.ageAnimal = 1;
        animalbase.poidsAnimal = 2;            
        return animalbase;
    }
}
 public class Reptile: AnimalBase
{
    public override string typeAnimal
    {
        get
        {
            return "Reptile";
        }
    }
    public Reptile():base()
    {

    }
}

   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //ERROR
        Reptile rep = (Reptile)AnimalBase.DoSomething("text");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Error:
{"Unable to cast object of type 'ConsoleApplication1.AnimalBase' to type 'ConsoleApplication1.Reptile'."}

I don't know why i have this problem, in msdn it says that i have just to specify the type explicitly.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You're going backwards... A `Reptile` is an `AnimalBase`, but not all `AnimalBase`s are `Reptile`s.

Comment: You should cast reptile to animalBase

Comment: How could i do it ? should i create a method that convert animalBase to reptile explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `AnimalBase.DoSomething` is returning an object whose concrete type is `AnimalBase`.

Try changing it to create a `Reptile` instance:

```
AnimalBase animalbase = new Reptile();
```

The reason this fails is because of your inheritance hierarchy. A `Reptile` **is-a** `AnimalBase`, but an `AnimalBase` is not necessarily a `Reptile`.